# Using functions in my controller using Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

I have various functions/methods in my controller.

index() --- loads the homepage view

```
$data['main_view'] = "home_view";         
$this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
```

view_all() --- loads some row count data

```
$this->load->model('home_model');
$data['result'] = $this->home_model->total_applications();        
$this->load->view('home_view', $data);
```

To load my homepage i goto url : www.mydomain.com/home
To view my method i have to goto : www.mydomain.com/home/view_all

I tried to load function view_all() in my view like this :

```
echo $result ---- and this throws out an error.
```

How do i load/call the fucntion view_all() when i visit www.mydomain.com/home. I have alot of functions in that controller and i want to use them on my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup routing in your configuration.
It is well described in documentation.

Comment: I just want to load a couple of my created functions in my home controller on my homepage view.

Comment: put your function1 result into $data['response1'],  function2 result into $data['response2']. Then you can pass $data to your view and display what you need in template.

Comment: could you please provide an example

Comment: Tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter--net-25648

Answer (score 0):

Ok , im not sure if this is the right way, but what i did was load all results from the model into one function and call them using :

```
$data['result1'] = $this->home_model->total_applications(); 
$data['result2'] = $this->home_model->total_applications2();   
$data['result3'] = $this->home_model->total_applications3();
```